# Reference file relative to the home directory

Tags: external-files, paths

How can I refer to a file (e.g. in `\includegraphics{}`) that lives in my home directory (I am on linux)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
not working: $\sim$/foo.png
%%\includegraphics{~/foo.png}

not working either: \$HOME/foo.png
%%\includegraphics{$HOME/foo.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\includegraphics{foo}` would work if your home directory is in your TEXINPUTS path, or `\includegraphics{\string~/foo}` should work on most systems.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Tanks for `\string~`.  That does work indeed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\includegraphics{foo}` would work if your home directory is in your `TEXINPUTS` path, or `\includegraphics{\string~/foo}` should work on most systems.

Comment: The `\string~` remains valid. Using PDFLATEX: pdflatex -version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)

Comment: Where can I find documentation of this use of `\string~`? I have needed this for a long time and just discovered your answer a decade late. And, thanks!

Comment: @Alan `texdoc  web2c` for example