# Specify path to home directory in Windows

Tags: paths

Is there any way to define a path relative to home in windows ?

Like it's done [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97770/reference-file-relative-to-the-home-directory) for linux

Comment: `~` should work

Comment: @Moriambar the link in the question is "how to input file in home directly into latex" so it is a tex question (just obscured)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers given in the linked question should work.

```
\input{\string~/abc}
```

for example.

The documentation of the comments (for example in

```
/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

or equivalent on your system) say

> ....  ~ expands to %USERPROFILE% on Windows, $HOME otherwise.

Comment: Right. Thanks! I had an error on my first try of this solution and thought it was platform specific.